# Very simple question - Autoload textbox when startup C#

Tags: c#, text, text-files, autoload

The tittle says it all :) I am creating a program in C# forms. The user can write a text, and save it. What i now want, is to autoload this textfile, witch only can be at one location - At the `Directory.GetCurrentDIrectory() + "text.txt"`.
So how should this be done?

Comment: have you not tried searching google first? http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ReadWriteTextFile.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to do this when the form is available, in which case I would recommend using the [Form Load event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx). Just open the file, read its contents, and set the `Text` property to the contents in the form load.

Comment: I wish i could vote you up, but i need 15 reputation to do that :(

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple really:

```
//Autoload
var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "text.txt");
if(File.Exists(filePath))
    yourTextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

As Ryan points out, you could do it in the FormLoad event.

Comment: I wish i could vote you up, but i need 15 reputation to do that :(

Comment: So just to be sure, take a look at this:

Comment: private void Main_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //The load code here
        }

Comment: I changed the filePath initialization to use Path.Combine. As per the docs, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory returns the "current working directory, and does not end with a backslash (\\).", which could mess things up.